# Python Request getting redirected to SSO

Tags: python-requests, request, python-3.8, python-requests-html

Hope everyone reading this is doing well.

I am working on fetching recovery keys from JAMF through Python, however, it seems like the request is getting redirected to an SSO webpage, which says that javascript is not enabled, so I don't get my session token for a further request.

I am using this repo - https://github.com/mikemackintosh/py-keysword

Code:

```
def getSessionToken():
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = jar
resp = s.post('{}/?failover'.format(JAMF_HOST), cookies=jar, data={'username':JAMF_USERNAME, 'password':JAMF_PASSWORD, 'resetUsername':''})
if resp.status_code != 200:
    print("Failed to Authenticate!")
    exit(1)

params = {"id": 29, "o": "r", "v": "management"}
resp = s.get('{}/legacy/computers.html'.format(JAMF_HOST), params=params, cookies=jar)
session_token = ""

print(resp.content)

# TODO: add error checking here
for line in resp.content.splitlines():
    if b"session-token" in line:
        return line.encode('utf-8').translate(None, '<>"').split('=')[-1]
print("Unable to find session token")
```

getSessionToken()

I then get this HTML response in resp.content with the SAMLRequest value and the continue button.

"b'\n\n    \n    \n    \n        \n

\n                **Note:** Since your browser does not support JavaScript,\n                you must press the Continue button once to proceed.\n

\n        "

Any clue how I can go about to circumvent this? I think I need a way to 'click' the button through my script to then get my session token but I am not sure how to go about that. Thanks!

Comment: Is there not a JAMF api available for developers?

Comment: There is, however, unfortunately it does not have the feature to get recovery keys.

This feature was actually requested by a lot of people and there are some jamf threads going on about it a while now. I think there security concerns about this but JAMF support pointed me to that repo since its everyone's workaround

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I think the simplest solution may be to use something like Selenium to interact with the JavaScript button and do it that way.